Why is $^{176}\rm{Lu}$ so stable with respect to $\beta^-$ decay?
The nuclide $^{176}\rm{Lu}$ (spin $7^-$) can decay to the $6^+$ state of $^{176}\rm{Hf}$, with a $Q$ value of $593.33\,\rm{keV}$. The change in spin $J$ and parity $π$ is only $\Delta J^{\Delta\pi} = 1^-$. Nevertheless, the half-life of $^{176}\rm{Lu}$ is as long as $3.701\times 10^{10}$ years. There are other $\beta$ decay processes with $\Delta J^{\Delta\pi} = 1^-$ and smaller $Q$ values whose half-life is short, for example the half-life of the EC decay $^{170}\rm{Tm}\to{}^{170}\rm{Er}$ ($1^-\to 0^+$, $313.99\,\rm{keV}$) is only hundreds of years (see NUBASE2020), and the half-life of the $\beta^-$ decay $^{113}\rm{{}^mCd}\to{}^{113}\rm{In}$ ($11/2^-\to 9/2^+$, $583.88\,\rm{keV}$) is only $14.1$ years. So why is the $7^-\to 6^+$ transition of $^{176}\rm{Lu}$ so different from the other two examples listed above?
The states of $^{176}\rm{Lu}$ can be seen here, and similarly for $^{170}\rm{Er}$ or $^{113}\rm{In}$.

Please consider [edit]ing your post to include relevant bits from the database you link to. The NNDC is great, but there's a steep learning curve. Furthermore they will eventually change their URL structure again, and your links won't work any more.

@rob I'm really sorry, but I did not understand what you meant by relevant bits and your suggestion to deal with the possibility of a link change. Did you mean that I should add something like "data from NNDC ..."?

I'm referring to your final sentence, where you invite people to dig into the database for level diagrams, which is kind of a hassle even when you already know how to use NNDC. Better to include those diagrams in your question (like I did in my answer) if you think they're appropriate.

@rob Thanks for your example.

I have an educated guess, but I'm interested in an answer from a proper nuclear structure expert, if one happens by.
Here's a decay scheme from the Experimental Unevaluated Nuclear Data List:



Have a look at that spectrum of hafnium states.  They all have the same parity, they are separated by $2\hbar$ units of spin, and their energies get further apart as the spin increases.  That's a classic sign of collective nuclear rotation, with a rigid rotor having kinetic energy $T\sim J^2$.
One model that might explain the discrepancy between lutetium and the other heavy isotopes you mention might be a transition between a single nucleon carrying most of the angular momentum, versus the entire nucleus sharing the angular momentum collectively.  The neighbor Lu-175 has a ground-state spin of $7/2^-$, so one hand-waving shell-model way to think about the transition to -176 is for the extra neutron to carry all of that extra angular momentum itself, in some parallel-aligned $J^P = 7/2^+$ orbital, giving the entire nucleus its overall $J^P=7^-$.  But the hafnium daughter nucleus, with its collective motion, doesn't have one or two outlying nucleons that hoard its angular momentum for themselves.  In shell-model description of a transition from a few-particle high-spin state to a many-particle high-spin state, many of the nucleons might have to switch to different orbitals.  That many-body transition would have a smaller matrix element than a transition where you can (to some extent) point at that neutron in that orbital and say "he is the one who changed flavor."
If you wanted to test this idea, rather than taking advice from someone on the internet who spent a summer baffled by nuclear structure in the late twentieth century, you might try to make some predictions.  Is the matrix element more like a $7\to0$ transition? In other nuclei with rotational bands, are the angular-momentum preference rules violated in similar ways?
There's a bunch of weird high-spin stuff happening in this region of the table of isotopes, far from any of the nuclear magic numbers. These mass-176 nuclei are not that far away from the mass-180 system, where tantalum-180 has a $1^+$ ground state that is unstable but a low-lying $9^-$ isomer that has never been observed to decay.

Thanks for you answer! I think I have got the general idea a bit, but making predictions remains hard to me. For example, consider the transition $^{212}\rm{^{m}At}\to{}^{212}\rm{Po}$ ($9^-\to 8^+$, $Q_{\rm{EC}}=271.84,\rm{keV}$). The level diagram of $^{212}\rm{Po}$ shows that there are $0^+$, $2^+$, $4^+$, $6^+$ and $8^+$ states, so the spin of $8^+$ is caused by collective nuclear rotation. What about $^{212}\rm{^{m}At}$? The states of $^{212}\rm{At}$ are $1^-$, $(1^-,2^-)$, $2^-$, $3^-$ and then $9^-$, is the spin of $9^-$ also collective nuclear rotation?

Part of the reason for the success of a collective-motion picture in the hafnium region is that those nuclei are far from any closed shells. Polonium-212 is one alpha decay away from doubly-magic Pb-208. If you want to see collective motion effects, look for nucleons with a large ground-state quadrupole parameter $\beta_2$, which is one of the things you can display on the NNDC's chart of isotopes. The low-lying polonium states you mention don't have $T\sim J^2$, so they don't look like a rotational band. The assignments of $J^P$ to the astatine-212 states all seem to be uncertain.

Thank you for your detailed explanation!
